# Show Eclipse Toolbar on Startup by default

Tags: eclipse

**Is it possible** to make the Eclipse toolbar always show by default when I start up eclipse?  If so, **how**?

Everytime I start up eclipse, I have to go to Window --> Show Toolbar.  I shouldn't have to do this if I want the toolbar all the time.

I've tried going to Window --> Customize Perspective... , where there is a "Tool Bar Visibility" tab.  But this seems to only have options for the visibility of the individual items, not the Toolbar itself.

I've also searched through the options under Window --> Preferences, but have not been able to find anything.

**So**, if I want the toolbar to be visible by default (in other words, be already visible whenever I start eclispe), what can I do?

(If it helps, I'm using Kepler on Windows 7.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select Window->Show Toolbar,
Then go to help->Welcome. The toolbar will be hidden again. Try to restore your perspective by minimizing the welcome screen. You should see the Eclipse toolbar again, next restart Eclipse.
This worked for me (with Kepler).

Answer (score 0):

You can save your perspective to the adhere to the changes you have made by right- clicking on Java or JavaEE in  the top-right side of Eclipse and selecting the Save as option

Comment: Maybe then updating or downloading the latest Eclipse version can only fix this problem

Comment: It's the latest version.  I literally downloaded it on a new laptop an hour before I asked the question.  I also have one that I downloaded when Kepler was released, with the same problem.  I'm beginning to think this is some sort of bug with no way to fix it.  Which is very sad.  :(